# Accordion menu not open when click

Tags: php, jquery

I have a simple accordion menu, but it's not opening when click.
The div is display:none, but when click in h3 title to show, not is happening.

```
<section class="informacoes">
<h3 class="h3">Informações Técnicas</h3> <!-- Click to open -->
<div class="cont">
<p>123 Test</p>
</div>
</section>
```

Style

```
h3.h3{ cursor: pointer; }
.cont{ display: none; }
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('h3.h3').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('.cont').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Other than a missing `</div>` in your example, seems to work fine. Have you checked dev tools to see any error output etc?

Comment: Sure, I have edited the post

Comment: Is jQuery loading in your document correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('h3.h3').click(function () {
            $(this).parent().find('.cont').slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <section class="informacoes">
        <h3 class="h3">Informações Técnicas</h3> <!-- Click to open -->
        <div class="cont" style="display: none;">
            <p>123 Test</p>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Andrea, this worked perfectly, I think the problem it's the jquery version, mine was old

Comment: @EvertonThomazi which jquery version have you tried? I've tried 1.12.4, 2.0 and 3.4.1